# Sed replace string with whitespaces

Tags: bash, replace, sed

I have a string which has a format like this :

```
{u city : u Zurich , u name : u Hauptbahnhof , u address : u Test address, C106, Bahnhofsstrasse }
```

I need to remove all the `" u "` (with the spaces) and replace the `", u "`(with the spaces) with a line breaker, but i have no idea how i could do that.

Is it possible with sed?

Output should be like

```
{city :Zurich 
name :Hauptbahnhof 
address :Test address, C106, Bahnhofsstrasse }
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Where did you obtain said string? To me it seems like an attempt to create JSON from Python, if so go fix your Python code.

Comment: it's from a json output which has been altered, but i have to use it like this unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following seems to work (with some whitespace differences):

```
's/, u /\n/g;s/\bu //g'
```

i.e. first replace all `", u "` with newlines, then remove all `u`, where `u` is not preceded by a word character.

Note that the output isn't a valid JSON.

Comment: This is really fragile, as any word ending with `u` will get it removed.

Comment: @andlrc: fixed.

Comment: i get the error "unterminated `s' command"
i use sed -e and i use it after a pipe, maybe that helps..

Comment: @Damon: please show the whole line. Also, what OS and sed version?

Comment: cat silo_json | sed -e 's/, u /\n/g;s/\bu //g' 

RHEL 6.8
GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: @Damon Works for me with the same sed version, weird. What about `sed -e 's/, u /\n/g' -e 's/\bu //g'`?

Comment: Omg.. my mistake i forgot to remove a sed statement in the script, your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `perl` command line substitution as below, used the `\b` tags for matching exact words and not mess up with other strings.

```
perl -pe 's/\bu \b//g;' -pe 's/\b , \b/\n/g;' file
{city : Zurich
name : Hauptbahnhof
address : Test address, C106, Bahnhofsstrasse }
```

And as pointed by others, if it is a broken `JSON` use `jq` or other ways to fix it.

Comment: same problem as above

 
i get the error "unterminated `s' command"
i have to use the string like that and output doesn't need to be json

Comment: i used a tmp-file for your example to check if it works

Comment: .. my mistake i forgot to remove a sed statement in the script, your solution works perfectly.

Comment: yeah sure, sorry that i gave him the solution but his worked too and he brought it up first, but thanks again